# Automatically push row downward

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to make a time sheet document, and I want it to be formatted

```
-----------------------------------------
|   Date   | Time In | Time Out | Hours |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/5/2014 |         |          |   0   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/4/2014 |  09:00  |  12:00   |   3   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/3/2014 |  09:30  |  14:00   |  4.5  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/2/2014 |  08:00  |  17:00   |   9   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/1/2014 |  12:00  |  13:00   |   1   |
-----------------------------------------
```

with the most recent date at the top.  I want to make it so that when I enter the times in the 1/5/2014 row, a new row automatically replaced 1/5/2014 with

```
-----------------------------------------
|   Date   | Time In | Time Out | Hours |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/6/2014 |         |          |   0   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/5/2014 |  09:00  |  13:00   |   4   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/4/2014 |  09:00  |  12:00   |   3   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/3/2014 |  09:30  |  14:00   |  4.5  |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/2/2014 |  08:00  |  17:00   |   9   |
-----------------------------------------
| 1/1/2014 |  12:00  |  13:00   |   1   |
-----------------------------------------
```

Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

A `Worksheet_Change` event macro would work well for this. Right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose View Code. When the VBE opens, paste the following into the right-hand pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:C2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.Count(Range("B2:C2")) = 2 Then
            On Error GoTo Fìn
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A2:D2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
            Range("A2") = Range("A3").Value + 1
            Range("D2").Formula = Replace(Range("D3").Formula, 3, 2)
            Range("B2").Activate
        End If
    End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Once B2 and C2 have been both had time values entered into them, a new row will be added with the appropriate formulas.

[image: Timecard add rows]

I've use the formula `=(C2-B2)*24` in column D.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!